# Are separate functions created for each object or only one per class?

Tags: c++, oop

For example in the following code, is a copy of `func1()` created for each `obj1`, `obj2`? Or is a single copy of `func1` shared between them?

```
class ABC
{
    int a;
    public:
        void  func1(void)
        {
            int k = 9;
            cout << "k = " << k;
        }
};
int main()
{
    ABC Obj1,Obj2;
    ......
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One function for all objects of type.

Comment: +1 One function per root class. If you have a method in A and two sub-classes, you still only have one method.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, each method exists only once as if you would have a normal c-style function to which a pointer is given:

```
    void func1(ABC *this)
    {
        int k = 9;
        cout << "k = " << k;
        this->a = 42;
    }

    ABC obj1;
    func1(&obj1);
```

This is only true as long you don't use inheritance with overloading. When using inheritance with overloading, a so called vtable comes into play, but that's another lesson...

Answer (score 0):

If you take the address of the function `&ABC::func1` it will always be the same address. It will not be different for each instance of ABC.

Note that it is a pointer to a function, and it always points to the same place.

Virtual functions have a different method of dispatch, where each derived class holds a table (v-table or virtual table) to what exact function is called for each one.

The obvious way to show this is in the language's `bind` function where you can do this:

```
std::function< void() > = std::bind( &ABC::func1, std::placeholders::_1 );
```

and you can subsequently pass in pointers / references to your `Obj1`, `Obj2` or `Obj3` to that `std::function`

Having said that there is only one function, do not be confused to think that it is not thread-safe.  Each time the function is invoked, there is a separate local instance of the variable `k`. This local variable is created new on the stack each time the function is invoked.